# correct use of prepositions

Tags: prepositions

Which of the following sentences has correct use of prepositions?
(A) I was angry ***at my results*** so I spoke with the teacher.
(B) I was angry ***with my results*** so I spoke to the teacher.

here results are not a person so it is a different question

Comment: The object of the anger here isn't a person (so *Speak to or speak with* doesn't seem appropriate, even if *speak* were the same as *being angry*); and it's not a situation either. The object of the anger is a thing. The "Angry with* question doesn't really cover that, I feel.

Answer (score -1):

You are angry neither *with* nor *at* your results, but **angry about / for** the results. See examples at [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/angry):

> **angry with/at somebody about/for something:**
>
> I was very angry with myself for making such a stupid mistake.
>
> The passengers grew angry about the delay.